# About Generating Random Unique and Secure PHP Strings

Tags: php, html

Hi guys I have a code to generate random unique strings, 12 charactes long.

```
$random_string = sha1(uniqid(rand(10, 1000), true));
$random_string  = substr($random_string  , rand(0, strlen($random_string  ) - 12), 12);
```

Is my code above safe for collision?
Any suggestions or modification to my above code?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Adding more calls to randomisation and hashing won't make your string "more random" or "more secure". What makes you think `uniqid` won't be enough?

Comment: You cut part of sha1 hash, this most likely increase chance of collisions

Comment: When I remove the hashing(sha1), I get a string with "." which I dont want to happen. :(

Comment: What are these random strings going to be used for? Chances are there's a standard best-practice way of doing whatever it is you want to do. If you tell us what you'er actually trying to achieve, we might be able to give you better advice about how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should look into [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) :

```
//returns 6 random bytes and in turn, bin2hex will make it a 12 characters string.
$rand = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(6));
```

//edit workaround :

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
    // doesn't use open ssl but you get the idea.
    function openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($len) {
        return file_get_contents('/dev/urandom', false, NULL, -1, $len); 
    }
}
$rand = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(6));
```

Comment: random pseudo-bytes, or pseudo-random bytes ? Gotta love those function names.

Comment: PHP function names in general are completely random and meaningless, annoying as hell in times.

Comment: @OneofOne I test you code, and it giving me an error "Call to undefined function openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()"

Comment: I just want a random and unique alphanumeric with 12 characters long that I can store into my database. Please help? :/